# How to ensure that a package is correctly installed/updated after "post-installation script: subprocess returned error exit status 1"

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, initramfs

After upgrading to Debian 10.7 I got this error, possibly due to lack of storage space: `Error while installing package: installed initramfs-tools package post installation script: subprocess returned error exit status 1`

How to ensure that the package is correctly installed? Should it be reinstalled (how)?

No packages are shown to remain to be upgraded when running `sudo apt-get auto-remove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` (except "python3-psycopg2" which is held back because "Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.7.3-1 is to be installed").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a package post installation script fails, the package remains in “half-configured” state, and any subsequent operation which touches packages *should* run the post installation script again.

You can check `initramfs-tools`’ state by running

```
dpkg -l initramfs-tools
```

If this shows

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name            Version       Architecture Description
+++-===============-=============-============-================================================
ii  initramfs-tools 0.133+deb10u1 all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
```

then nothing further needs to be done.

If the second column shows `F`, then the package is half-configured, and configuration can be completed by running

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

If you’d rather re-install the package instead, run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools
```

Comment: It showed the result that indicates that nothing needs to be done. Why did it return an error exit status 1 in that case? If that command/output makes sure that it doesn't need to be reinstalled or reconfigured all the better.

Comment: The upgrade would normally run the failing installation script again; presumably it worked the second time round.